# Routing exception after upgrading to TYPO3 v9.5.14

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, tx-news, symfony-routing

After upgrading to TYPO3 v9.5.14 our detail pages for news crash with the exception

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\InvalidParameterException
>
> Parameter "p88bd715a41119d0e8087a5d19cb049" for route "tx_news_pi1_1" must match "[^/]++" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL.

What's going on?

The site used this configuration:

```
  NewsTagPlugin:
    type: Extbase
    limitToPages: [14]
    extension: News
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      - routePath: '/{tag-name}'
        _controller: 'News::list'
        _arguments:
          tag-name: 'overwriteDemand/tags'
      - routePath: '/{tag-name}/page/{page}'
        _controller: 'News::list'
        _arguments:
          tag-name: 'overwriteDemand/tags'
          page: '@widget_0/currentPage'
          requirements:
            page: '\d+'
    defaultController: 'News::list'
    defaults:
      page: ''
    aspects:
      page:
        type: IntegerMapper
        start: 1
        end: 5000
      tag-name:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_news_domain_model_tag
        routeFieldName: slug
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 1) Superfluous mapping

```
  NewsTagPlugin:
    ...
    routes:
      ...
      - routePath: '/{tag-name}/page/{page}'
        _controller: 'News::list'
        _arguments:
          tag-name: 'overwriteDemand/tags'
          page: '@widget_0/currentPage'
          requirements:
            page: '\d+'
```

- `_arguments` defines a mapping for route parameter and internal variables (e.g. as query parameter`
- `requirements` is wrong here, since it shall not be used as argument mapping
- parameter `requirements` need to be defined on the root level of `NewsTagPlugin`

### 2) Invalid empty default value

```
  NewsTagPlugin:
    ...
    routes:
      ...
      - routePath: '/{tag-name}/page/{page}'
      ...
    defaults:
      page: ''
    aspects:
      ...
```

- `defaults` was not applied prior to TYPO3 v9.5.14 and addressed in https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/60361
- the empty default value for parameter `page` does not make much sense and would lead to an URL like `/some-tag/page/` which is causing the error message shown in the answer
- the default value should be `page: 1`
- in case the parameter should be omitted in the URL (e.g. having `/some-tag/page/`) this needs to be defined explicitly using `{!page}` in the route path

### References

- https://symfony.com/doc/4.3/routing.html#optional-parameters
- https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.5.x/Important-86895-RouteAspectsTakePrecedenceOverRequirements.html

### Adjusted enhancer configuration

```
  NewsTagPlugin:
    type: Extbase
    limitToPages: [14]
    extension: News
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      - routePath: '/{tag-name}'
        _controller: 'News::list'
        _arguments:
          tag-name: 'overwriteDemand/tags'
      - routePath: '/{tag-name}/page/{!page}'
        _controller: 'News::list'
        _arguments:
          tag-name: 'overwriteDemand/tags'
          page: '@widget_0/currentPage'
    defaultController: 'News::list'
    defaults:
      page: 1
    aspects:
      page:
        type: IntegerMapper
        start: 1
        end: 5000
      tag-name:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_news_domain_model_tag
        routeFieldName: slug
```

- (untested) since `IntegerMapper` seems to be a custom aspect implementation - not being available to the public

Comment: I disagree on some points. The setup described in the question worked without errors in 9.5.13.
The URLs for the pages were
/tag-name/
/tag-name/page/2
/tag-name/page/3

This was working and required the setup to have the default value as empty string.
Your example assumes page:1 as default, which is wrong for the desired URLs.

Comment: `IntegerMapper` is indeed a custom mapper, that does nothing special except being faster than what the core shipped so far.

Answer (score 0):

First off, consider https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.5.x/Important-86895-RouteAspectsTakePrecedenceOverRequirements.html

The culprit is the `default` configuration for the `page` aspect.
It was once introduced to make sure that the URL for the first tag page is always "/tag-name" and only subsequent pages have "/tag-name/page/2" and so on.

This default value now needs to be removed in order to have the requirements applied as desired.